Why is 'это' neuter in this expression?
In this sentence - 'какой это цвет' the demonstrative  pronoun is neuter nominative singular - I would have expected 'этот' to agree with masculine 'какой' and 'цвет'.

The point is that you consider «это» to be a demonstrative pronoun in the attributive function like это окно (neuter gender).
But that case is different. It is a subject of the indefinite personal sentence
(подразумеваемый субъект неопределенно-личного предложения) it never changes, always это
Like in "What color is it? — It's blue." Это синий.
В дверь постучали, и Андрей спрыгнул со стола. – Кто это? – спросил он. – Это Авэль, – проговорил бас за дверью. [В. Пелевин. Желтая стрела (1993)]

"Это" is a substantival pronoun (this) and like nouns, it has a fixed gender (neuter in this case).
Not to be confused with the adjectival pronoun "этот" which, like adjectives, changes gender with the word it depends on: этот цвет, эта машина, это окно, эти очки.

I regard it as an analogue of "it" in English. What colour is it? Note things like это был мужчина - it was/that was a man. There is another thread on Stackexchange from 8 years about Чей это кот?, which is also the same sort of thing (whose cat is it?).
